# User Authentication taking a long time in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using  a `ModelViewSet` with the `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` permission class, like so:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, MarkdownToHTML):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

When I call this view in the browsable API, the data returns in about 1100 ms (already too long), but when I call it from my frontend UI, the call takes 6000-7000ms!

The only difference between these two methods of calling the same view is that I am passing along a json token from my frontend UI app. When I comment out the token header, the response returns in about 1 second, the same time as in the browsable API.

How could this simple authentication step take over 5 seconds?

Here is the permission class:

```
class IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    """
    The request is authenticated as a user, or is a read-only request.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return (
            request.method in SAFE_METHODS or
            request.user and
            request.user.is_authenticated
        )
```

Comment: This isn't the authentication class though. It is the permission class

Comment: Thanks, I edited to remove that incorrect reference

Answer (score 2):

I've run in a similar issue in a project. I would tell you about my experience in order to try to help, I can't tell what is your exact problem but I'll post things I checked when I had mine.

The thing is that decoding the auth token is a very expensive operation, so you have to check:

1. How many times is such token (if provided) decoded in your view?
2. Can you use cookies for caching auth token, setting an expire time?
3. How many time is this token send to and back from the server?

On the other hand, remember DRF will transform you json to a python object (specifically a dictionary) depending on the length of your token (and how many times it occurs) it will be a very expensive operation too.

Comment: As far as testing it, I haven't yet figured out how to pass an auth token when calling the endpoint from the browsable API, thereby passing through the debug toolbar. Do you have any suggestions for testing the view ?

Comment: Yes, you can use, the test.Client class. As you will see you can set headers to perform the request.

Comment: You can also use a tool like Postman to make request to your API. Also I recommend you to use some profiler in order to find out where your time is goin on.